# Should we make the [starspot] and [sunspots] tags synonyms?

Tags: discussion

This suggestion was made in the comments to the question [Do brown dwarfs have starspots?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/44771/) It is about [sunspots](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sunspots) (**9** questions) vs. [starspot](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starspot) (**6** questions) . The latter tag I recently created. The user [@John](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/40738/john) wrote:

> I ain't sure if it's a good idea to create two separate tags sun- and starspot. The Sun is a star. I suggest sunspot be made synonymous with starspot, and if they're ones concerning the Sun you can add the tag Sun to your question.

I tend to agree with that. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I'm not so sure. Are they technically the same phenomena? Yes. However, just like with planet vs. exoplanet, the study of each is very different.

Comment: Since observed starspots are *huge* (the ones imaged or detected are of order the diameter of the star itself) and can happen on stars very, very different than our Sun, they really may not be the same phenomenon. And since even then they are barely resolved the underlying phenomenon might not be star spots at all; a question tagged starspot [might turn out to be passing globs of dust in front of the star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betelgeuse#2019%E2%80%9320_fading) or even something else. I'd leave them separate.

Answer (score 2):

Converting my [comment](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/779/should-we-make-the-starspot-and-sunspots-tags-synonyms#comment2703_779) to an answer in order to spark some activity and perhaps other viewpoints:

> Since observed starspots are huge (the ones imaged or detected are of order the diameter of the star itself) and can happen on stars very, very different than our Sun, they really may not be the same phenomenon. And since even then they are barely resolved the underlying phenomenon might not be star spots at all; a question tagged starspot [might turn out to be passing globs of dust in front of the star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betelgeuse#2019%E2%80%9320_fading) or even something else. I'd leave them separate.